# Select a particular column using awk or cut or perl

Tags: perl, unix, sed, awk

I have a requirement to select the 7th column from a tab delimited file. eg:

```
cat filename | awk '{print $7}'
```

The issue is that the data in the 4th column has multiple values with blank in between. example - The last line in the below output:

```
user  \Adminis FL_vol Design         0         -       1       -
group        0 FL_vol Design   19324481         -    3014       -
user      \MAK FL_vol Design   16875161         -    2618       -
tree       826 FL_vol Out Global Doc Mark     16875162         -    9618       - /vol/FL_vol/Out Global Doc Mark
```

Answer (score 29):

If the data is unambiguously tab-separated, then `cut` will cut on tabs, not spaces:

```
cut -f7 filename
```

You can certainly do that with `awk`, too:

```
awk -F'\t' '{ print $7 }'
```

Answer (score 6):

If fields are separated by tabs and your concern is that some fields contain spaces, there is no problem here, just:

```
cut -f 7
```

(cut defaults to tab delimited fields.)

Answer (score 4):

Judging by the format of your input file, you can get away with delimiting on `-` instead of spaces:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="-"} {print $2}' filename
```

- `FS` stands for Field Separator, just think of it as the delimiter for input.
- Given that we are now delimiting on `-`, your 7th field before now becomes the 2nd field.
- [Save a cat](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html)! Specify input file `filename` as an argument to awk instead.

---

Alternatively, if your data fields are separated by tabs, you can do it more explicitly as follows:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"} {print $7}' filename
```

And this will resolve the issue since `Out Global Doc Mark` looks to be separated by spaces.

Comment: ... And whipe space: `awk 'BEGIN{FS="[ \t]*-[ \t]*"} {print $2}'`

Comment: Sometimes the 5th column has numbers in it. It need not be a "-" all the time. Also it could be a "-" in the 4th column instead.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/(([^\t]*)\t?){7}.*/\2/' file
```

---

This substitute command selects everything in the line and returns the 7th non-tab. In `sed` the last thing grouped by `(...)` will be returned in the lefthand side of the substitution by using a back-reference. In this case the first back-reference would return both the non-tab characters and the tab character (if present N.B. the `?` meta-character which either one or none of the proceeding pattern).The `.*` just swallows up what was left on the line if any.

Comment: @shgnInc the substitute command selects everything in the line and returns the 7th non-tab. In sed the last thing grouped by `(...)` will be returned in the lefthand side of the substitution by using a backreference. In this case the first backreference would return both the non-tab characters and the tab character (if present N.B. the `?` metacharacter which either one or none of the preceeding pattern).The `.*` just swallows up what was left on the line if any.