# Get specific output from grep

Tags: linux, bash, grep, cri-o

I am trying to get a specific output using grep but I am unable to do so.
Here is my grep command :

`crictl inspect 47aaecb541688accf37840108cc0d19b39b84f8337740edf2ca7e5e81a24328e | grep "io.kubernetes.pod.namespace"`

The output of the above command is `"io.kubernetes.pod.namespace": "kube-system",`

I even tried 
`crictl inspect 47aaecb541688accf37840108cc0d19b39b84f8337740edf2ca7e5e81a24328e | grep  -Po '(?<="io.kubernetes.pod.namespace": ").*'` but the output i got is `kube-system",`

I just want the value i.e just `kube-system`

How do I modify my grep command. 
Thanks for the help

Comment: `grep` is the wrong tool.  `crictl ... | awk '/io.kubernetes.pod.namespace/ { print $4 }' FS=\"`

Comment: or `awk -F\" '/io.kubernetes.pod.namespace/{print $4}'`

Comment: Try `cut -f 2 -d ':'` instead of `grep`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the second column from command output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16136943/608639), [Select a particular column using awk or cut or perl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13795196/608639), [How can I get 2nd and third column in tab delim file in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6312564/608639), [Extracting columns from text file with different delimiters in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19959746/608639), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using grep

We need to make just one small change to the `grep -P` command.  Your command was:

```
$ echo '"io.kubernetes.pod.namespace": "kube-system",' | grep  -Po '(?<="io.kubernetes.pod.namespace": ").*'
kube-system",
```

We just need to replace `.*` (which matches everything to the end of the line) with `[^"]*` with matches everything up to but not including the first `"`:

```
$ echo '"io.kubernetes.pod.namespace": "kube-system",' | grep  -Po '(?<="io.kubernetes.pod.namespace": ")[^"]*'
kube-system
```

Or, using your `crictl` command:

```
crictl inspect 47aaecb541688accf37840108cc0d19b39b84f8337740edf2ca7e5e81a24328e | grep  -Po '(?<="io.kubernetes.pod.namespace": ")[^"]*'
```

#### Using sed

```
$ echo '"io.kubernetes.pod.namespace": "kube-system",' | sed -n '/"io.kubernetes.pod.namespace"/{s/.*": "//; s/".*//p}'
kube-system
```

How it works:

- `-n` tells sed not to print unless we explicitly ask it to.
- `/"io.kubernetes.pod.namespace"/{...}` selects only those lines that contain `"io.kubernetes.pod.namespace"` and performs the commands in braces on them.
- `s/.*": "//` removes everything from the beginning of the line to the last occurrence of `": "`.
- `s/".*//p` removes everything from the first remaining `"` to the end of the line and prints the result.